# How do I group by date in Crystal Reports 8.0?

Tags: crystal-reports, sql-server-2000

I have a Crystal Report that looks like:

*Date | Person | Ticket | Summary 

Date | Person | Ticket | Summary 

Date | Person | Ticket | Summary*

I would like it to look like:

*Date 

Person | Ticket | Summary 
 
Person | Ticket | Summary 


Date 

Person | Ticket | Summary*

All values are pulled from a MS SQL 2000 database, the application that will ultimately use the report is a VB 6 app that I unfortunately have to support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crystal has a function to add a grouping and all you need to do is select your date field into it.  You should be able to do this by right-clicking on the date field and selecting the 'group by' option!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The old version of crystal I was using didn't have a right click menu for grouping, but I was able to select insert > group and I was on my way.

Answer (score 1):

JFV has the right answer.  The only additional thing to watch for is when adding the group the last drop down on the "Common" tab ("This section will be printed:") sets that you want to group the data by date rather than by hour, week, month year or whatever time period.
If you haven't set this and your datetime field in the database also contains a time part, you may end up with more groups than you anticipated.
If you forgot to set the "This section will be printed:" option, right click on the section part and select "Change Group..."